# Decode Json to array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a `json` object in this structure :

```html
{
  "a": {
    "a": "10",
    "q": "dumb text"
  },
  "b": {
    "a": "23:00",
    "q": "dumb text"
  },
  "c": {
    "a": null,
    "q": "dumb text"
  }
}
```

And i'm looking to get an array from this object like :

```html
[{ "a": "10", "q": "dumb text 1" }, { "a": "20", "q": "dumb text 2" },{ "a": "30", "q": "dumb text 3" }]
```

Is there a way to achieve this result ?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Just array_values?

Comment: It would  be easier  to understand if the data in the desired output matched the data in the input

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP's built-in [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function to decode your JSON payload.

This will return you an stdClass object whose properties will contain your 2nd level objects.

Casting this object to an array will preserve your 2nd level objects.

If you need to convert the result back to JSON, use the [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) method.

https://3v4l.org/WI4en